# How can I check if Scrapy Image Pipeline is using a proxy to download images?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-pipeline

I have built a scraper and would like to download some images using a proxy in scrapy. I don't know if it is really downloading through the proxy. Reponse Headers don't show the IP. Furthermore, if I change the IP to a random IP, it still downloads the Image. 
How can I ensure it is using a proxy to download the images?
Thanks

**Pipelines.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        meta = {'proxy': 'http://23.323.44.22:11111/'}
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url,meta=meta)
```

**Settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'myproject.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline': 1}
```

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the download works with a *random IP*, the proxy is not used.

The [Scrapy Doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy) says:
"You can also set the meta key `proxy` per-request, to a value like `http://some_proxy_server:port`. Maybe the '/' at the end of your proxy url confuses Scrapy?

To make sure that a proxy is used, I would use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and filters on the proxy IP. If you see traffic for it's IP, it is likely that it is used.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and report.